# Symfony UX and VueJs - multi-bundle structure

Tags: symfony, vuejs3, symfonyux

I just saw that Symfony has a bundle to integrate VueJs 3.
https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-vue/current/index.html

Has anyone already tried that - it would be interesting if it's possible to serve views in a multi-bundle structure.
Imagine you have a "LoginBundle" where you want to serve everything auth-related and a "Settingsbundle" where you want to provide additional views for system settings (or whatever).

Has anyone already tried that?